# Magento 1 Product Tag Pages and Meta Data

Tags: tags, product, magento-1.9

At Magento 1.9, I noticed that the meta description tag of the Product Tag pages is actually the text configured at field System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design > HTML Head > Default Description. Similarly, the meta keywords tag of the Product Tag pages is actually the text configured at field System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design > HTML Head > Default Keywords. For example, the following Product Tag page:

https://www.dlastore.com/e_store/tag/product/list/tagId/22938/

This results to having a large number of pages with the same content for meta description and keywords tags, something that search engines don't generally like. Is there any way to change that programmatically and use the text appearing at the title of the Product Tag pages for the meta description and keywords?

The text appearing at the title of the Product Tag pages is unique per page, so a solution like this would be fine.

Comment: hey Dimitris, 
Did you got any solution for your question,
I'm also running in the same situation...

Comment: Yes, I found a solution myself, but it is strongly bound with the kind of items I'm selling. I'm now waiting to see how this solution is assessed by the search engines.

Comment: I tried a temporary solution i.e. as I have to change the Title for a few pages, I'm setting those tagged products pages' Title based on their URLs kind of working for me, but Still, I'm looking for a permanent solution if possible, btw I'm glad you replied and Thank you for your reply :-)